# UIKit - Как удалить выделенный текст в TextField?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста, как мне удалить выделенный текст в TextField? При нажатий на кнопку мне нужно удалить выделенный текст, если текст не выбран нужно удалить символ который находится перед курсором.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот такой примерчик набросал по вашим условиям

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var textField: UITextField!

    @IBAction func buttonTouchUpInside(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if !textField.isFirstResponder {
            print("text field is not focused")
            return
        }

        if textFieldHasSelection(textField) {
            removeSelectedTextIn(textField: textField)
        } else {
            removeCharacterAtCaretPositionIn(textField: textField)
        }
    }

    func textFieldHasSelection(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if textField.text == nil || textField.text?.count == 0 {
            return false
        }

        guard let selectedTextRange = textField.selectedTextRange else {
            return false
        }

        return textField.offset(from: selectedTextRange.start, to: selectedTextRange.end) > 0
    }

    func removeSelectedTextIn(textField: UITextField) {
        guard let text = textField.text else {
            return
        }

        guard let selectedTextRange = textField.selectedTextRange else {
            return
        }

        let location = textField.offset(from: textField.beginningOfDocument, to: selectedTextRange.start)
        let length = textField.offset(from: selectedTextRange.start, to: selectedTextRange.end)

        let startIndex = text.index(text.startIndex, offsetBy: location)
        let endIndex = text.index(startIndex, offsetBy: length)

        textField.text = text.replacingCharacters(in: startIndex..<endIndex, with: "")
    }

    func removeCharacterAtCaretPositionIn(textField: UITextField) {
        guard let text = textField.text else {
            return
        }

        guard let selectedTextRange = textField.selectedTextRange else {
            return
        }

        let location = textField.offset(from: textField.beginningOfDocument, to: selectedTextRange.start)
        let length = 1

        if location == 0 {
            return
        }

        let startIndex = text.index(text.startIndex, offsetBy: location - 1)
        let endIndex = text.index(startIndex, offsetBy: length)

        textField.text = text.replacingCharacters(in: startIndex..<endIndex, with: "")

        // сдвигаем курсор на 1 символ назад

        if let newPosition = textField.position(from: selectedTextRange.start, offset: -1) {
            textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textRange(from: newPosition, to: newPosition)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо !!